# Angular2 - Meteor - How to customize accounts-ui layout

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor, angular, meteor-accounts, angular2-meteor

I have been following this very interesting [tutorial](http://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular2/privacy-and-publish-subscribe-functions) about using angular2 with Meteor.

Everything went smoothly, but now I would like to use my own Bootstrap 3 modal for the sign in/ login features.

The tutorial uses [ng2-meteor-accounts-ui](https://atmospherejs.com/barbatus/ng2-meteor-accounts-ui) which is "a wrapper for  "accounts-ui" package's loginButtons view".

I have found resources and documentation on how to customise the Meteor-accounts-ui default package but nothing on this one. I tried to look at the source but the meteor modules are available only in the "build" folder after build time, and all the HTML is built by concatenating JS strings.

I have no idea of how to edit this because of the lack of documentation. Do I have to build my on ng2 wrapper for the meteor package ?

Comment: Hi @Rayjax, have you succeed to customize accounts-ui layout? I also met the same problem. Thanks

Comment: Frankly, I switched back to meteor/blaze. Too many alpha-unstable-notdocumented-notintegrated--notcommunityknown problems. But it's been a few months now, ng2 is now beta, I guess the integration with meteor itself is going to become more and more mature. If you do find a solution please answer, I will gladly accept it.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! I will post here once I find the way.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete the {{> logginButtons }}
and make the call to the methods directly:

```
 Meteor.loginWithFacebook({
    requestPermissions: ['public_profile', 'user_location', 'user_photos']
  }, function (err) {
    console.log(err);
    if (err)
    {
      Session.set('errorMessage', err.reason || 'Unknown error');
    }
    else {

      $state.go('menu.home', {reloadUser: true}, {reload: true});
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several options..

1. you can put the `{{> logginButtons }}` into a modal
2. you can use the `accounts-ui-unstyled` package to get rid of the default styling
3. You can remove `accounts-ui` at all and build your ui by your self, just use the built-in methods to interact with the server

http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_loginwithpassword
http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_loginwithexternalservice

Comment: Sadly, I removed Blaze, as I use angular2 as a frontend framework. I could add blaze back and use {{>loginButtons}} but it would be a dirty solution to use both frontend frameworks. I am using barbatus wrapper for accounts-ui, so I am not able to find an unstyled version. Your third option seems to be the best one, I will have to bind all the buttons to the Meteor methods from the angular UI

Comment: @Rayjax then use the 3. variant.. remove accounts-ui and use the api methods by your self